# Dojo Upload file from dijit Tree

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to reuse someone's code where am getting list files from a dialog. From the list when I choose a file, I can get the name of the file and other details. Now I need to upload this file once I get it but I've looked around but can't find anything providing such solution, the only thing am coming across is dojo uploader and the like. I just want to be able to upload the file manually and also be able to use it as when I receive a file from `dojox.form.Uploader`.

Comment: Can you provide some more details or code which you use?

Comment: Am sorry but can't show code. I mean, I have a working dijit Tree containing files which I can select successfully and once I select I can get the file name, id etc. Now once I selected a file successfully I want to upload it using dojo uploader, is it possible?

Comment: Have you searched the [docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.9/dojox/form/Uploader.html) or seen the [tests](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/form/tests/)?